# Best way to spread ~4gb of data(windows updates) to ~50clients

Tags: windows, windows-update, robocopy, wsus-offline

I have a few Windows updates of a few operating systems. Those are made with the program wsusoffline and contain several .cab and .exe files. I got those on a USB. What is the best way to deploy them to around 50clients? I was thinking about putting them on a networknl drive and let the clients download them thru robocopy. Any better ideas?

I know about WSUS and how it works. But I don't want to download the updates through WSUS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the client PCs in a Domain?

Comment: @TimHaegele yes they are. Are you thinking about GPO?

Comment: Yes. A robocopy script in GPO would work

Comment: @TimHaegele I actually never worked with GPO before, is it hard to do?

Comment: simple. Problem can be the high network load, if the script satrts synchron on all PCs. You can also use "psexec". That way you have more control over the network-load

Comment: Thank you @TimHaegele for helping me out. I am gonna do some research in those tools